# AJAX JS PHP HTML multiple same name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a multiple form generated from PHP and i put there HTML inputs with IDs and NAMEs. 
only i cannot figure out how to catch all this stuff.
If i press one button "Done" everything became done cause of the name of buttons

```
<?$command = "SELECT * FROM example ";
$query1 = $db->query($command);
while ($rowExample = $query1->fetch()) {?>
<div data-role="collapsibleset" style="padding-left:10px;">

    <form id = "form">
        <div style=" font-weight:400;" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u" data-inset="false">
            <h3><span style="color:#ff9884"><?echo$rowExample['postcode'] ;?> </span><span style="color:#9fd6d9;"><?echo $rowExample['address'];?></span></h3>
            <p><?echo $rowExample[title]?></p>

            <p><a href="tel:<?echo $rowExample[phone]?>"><?echo $rowExample[phone]. "</a>  " .$rowExample[FullName];?></p>

            <p><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/<?echo str_replace(" ","+",$rowExample['postcode']);?>"><?echo $rowExample['postcode']?></a> <?echo  $rowExample['address']?></p>


            <input type="hidden" id="orderID" name="orderID" value="<? echo $rowExample['orderID']?>">
            <input type="hidden" id="destination" name="destination" value="<? echo $rowExample['orderDestination']?>">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="ui-corner-all" style="background-color:#6B8761;">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Done</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <div class="ui-corner-all" style="background-color:#587C87;"><button type="submit" id="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Go to Info</button></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <div class="ui-corner-all" style="background-color:#946354;"><button type="submit" id="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Skipped</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and the most interesting is JS i please advise on it

```
    $('#submit').click(function(){

var orderID = $('#orderID').val();
var destination = $('#destination').val();

var data = 'orderID='+orderID+'&destination='+destination;
console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "worker/worker.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        alert("It was Done");
    }
});
return false;
   });
```

this show me all the generated forms.
but i need just only that o that the click was executed

Comment: You're re-using the same `id` values multiple times in the page.  (1) This is invalid.  (2) Even aside from it being invalid, logically when you get the value for an element by its `id` and there's more than one, which element do you *expect* to get?

Comment: that's the problem i know, and i cannot figure it out :(

Comment: Use classes instead.

Comment: waaa? how classes could help me? =/

Comment: additionally... never use id="submit" or id="reset", it mangles the form's submit and reset methods.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is better to add a unique id to every form. Then you can find which form has been submitted by using .closest method. You should use class when you want to select same elements and use id when you want to use unique element. So using the same id "submit" for all submit elements is not good. Use class in place of id. You can see an example usage in form tag.

```js
$('#submit').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var formId = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");

 var orderID = $('#'+ formId +' #orderID').val();
 var destination = $('#'+ formId +' #destination').val();

 var data = 'orderID='+orderID+'&destination='+destination;
 console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "worker/worker.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        alert("It was Done");
    }
});
return false;
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
    $i = 0
    while ($rowExample = $query1->fetch()) {
    $i++;
    ?>
        <form class="form" id="form-<?php echo $i;?>">
            ...
        </form>
   
    <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, replace your `id` values with `class` values so the markup is at least valid.  So for example:

```
<form id = "form">
```

might become:

```
<form class = "form">
```

or even just:

```
<form>
```

if you don't need to use that `id` or `class` at all.  (Unless there's a need I'm not seeing, you probably don't need *any* of your `id`s in this code.  But I may be incorrect on that.  Your own testing and validation will determine that.)

---

Then, step back for a moment and ask yourself... **What should that submit button *do*?**

Currently your code answers that question as:

> Get *the* value from *the* order ID and *the* destination and send it in an AJAX request.

But... You have *multiple* order ID inputs and *multiple* destination inputs.  So which one is *the* input?

Instead, consider this as the answer to the question:

> For the form in which the button was clicked, get *the* value from *the* order ID and *the* destination and send it in an AJAX request.

That identifies specifically which inputs you want.

---

So first we need a single click handler for all of the submit buttons.  Easy enough:

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    // code described below will go here
});
```

So now for any click on any button of `type="submit"`, this function will be invoked.  And what will this function do?  Get the inputs *for the current form*.  In jQuery terms, this would generally involve some DOM traversal to identify the elements you want.  Logically, you want to refer to the containing `<form>` and find the `<input>` elements therein.

Something like this should work:

```
var orderID = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="orderID"]').val();
```

Basically, starting from "this" (the button that was clicked), move up the HTML to the closest `<form>`, then within that form find the `<input>` you're looking for by its name.  (If you ever have more than one `<input>` of the same name in the same `<form>` then you would of course need to adjust this.)

Repeat for the `destination` value too.  And at that point the rest of your code *should* have the specific values you're looking for (instead of *all* of the values on the page) and the AJAX request *should* be what you expect it to be.

Comment: it would probably be a hell of a lot simpler to just use the form submit event, no? Then he could simply serialize the form to get the param string, thus fixing yet another problem with his code.

Comment: @KevinB: Valid point.  Given the original code, I imagine a lot of things could make this simpler.  I'm merely trying to illustrate the concept for the OP.